# Why $E(b^TUU^Tb)=0$ is equivalent to $b \perp span[E(UU^T)]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

If U is a random matrix whose entries are square integrable, and $\mathcal{F}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^p$, then the following statements are equivalent.

1. span(U) $\subset \mathcal{F}$ a.s. P;
2. span($E(UU^T)$) $\subset \mathcal{F}$.

The textbook gives a proof.

Proof: we first show that

$$ b \perp U a.s. P \iff b \perp span[E(UU^T)]$$

This is because

$$b \perp U a.s. P \iff b^TU=0 a.s.P$$

$$\iff b^TUU^Tb=0 a.s. P$$

$$\iff E(b^TUU^Tb)=0$$

$$\iff b \perp span[E(UU^T)]$$

Now statement 1 holds if and only if $\mathcal{F}^\perp \subset span(U)^\perp a.s. P,$ which is equivalent to $\mathcal{F}^\perp \subset span(E(UU^T))^\perp a.s. P$. This is equivalent to statement 2.

My question: I don't understand how the last $\iff$ holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $b$ is non-random, we have $E[b^\top UU^\top b] = b^\top E[UU^\top] b$.

If $b$ is orthogonal to the columns of $E[UU^\top]$, then $b^\top E[UU^\top] b = 0^\top b = 0$. This proves the $\impliedby$ direction.

For the $\implies$ direction, note that $E[UU^\top]$ is some [non-random] symmetric matrix, which [can be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) written as $E[UU^\top] = LL^\top$ for some square matrix $L$. [I am *not* claiming that $L=E[U]$.] Then $$0 = b^\top LL^\top b = \|L^\top b\|^2.$$ Thus $b^\top L = 0$ and moreover $0 = b^\top LL^\top = b^\top E[UU^\top]$.